# base64 image doesn't display in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, base64, mern

I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work  I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work  I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work  I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work  I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work  I am trying to display base64 in react js but it doesn't work

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { userContext } from '../../App';
import './Profile.css';
let k=1;

const Profile = () => {
    const[data,setData]=useState({});
    const[report,setReport]=useState({});
    const[login,setLogin]= useContext(userContext);
      if(data.length>0){
        sessionStorage.setItem('login', true)
        setLogin(1)
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
     
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/Singup/Profile?username='+sessionStorage.getItem('username'),{
          method: 'GET',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            "authorization" : `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("Token")}`

          }
        })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res=>setData(res))
    },[])
  
   
    useEffect(()=>{
     
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/Upload/ReportPost?username='+sessionStorage.getItem('username'),{
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(res=>
     setReport(res) 
      )
  },[])
  useEffect(()=>{
    report&& console.log(report)
  })
    return (
        <div class="container">
       { data[0] && <div class="row gutters-sm">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
                <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png" alt="Admin" class="rounded-circle" width="150"/>
                <div class="mt-3">
                  <h4>{data[0].username && data[0].username}</h4>
                  <p class="text-secondary mb-1">A family mamber of bongocare</p>
                  <p class="text-muted font-size-sm">{data[0].address&& data[0].address}</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Follow</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Message</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <h6 class="mb-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-globe mr-2 icon-inline"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="2" y1="12" x2="22" y2="12"></line><path d="M12 2a15.3 15.3 0 0 1 4 10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1-4 10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1-4-10 15.3 15.3 0 0 1 4-10z"></path></svg>Name</h6>
                <span class="text-secondary"> {data[0].name && data[0].name}</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <h6 class="mb-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-github mr-2 icon-inline"><path d="M9 19c-5 1.5-5-2.5-7-3m14 6v-3.87a3.37 3.37 0 0 0-.94-2.61c3.14-.35 6.44-1.54 6.44-7A5.44 5.44 0 0 0 20 4.77 5.07 5.07 0 0 0 19.91 1S18.73.65 16 2.48a13.38 13.38 0 0 0-7 0C6.27.65 5.09 1 5.09 1A5.07 5.07 0 0 0 5 4.77a5.44 5.44 0 0 0-1.5 3.78c0 5.42 3.3 6.61 6.44 7A3.37 3.37 0 0 0 9 18.13V22"></path></svg>Email</h6>
                <span class="text-secondary">  {data[0].email && data[0].email}</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <h6 class="mb-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-twitter mr-2 icon-inline text-info"><path d="M23 3a10.9 10.9 0 0 1-3.14 1.53 4.48 4.48 0 0 0-7.86 3v1A10.66 10.66 0 0 1 3 4s-4 9 5 13a11.64 11.64 0 0 1-7 2c9 5 20 0 20-11.5a4.5 4.5 0 0 0-.08-.83A7.72 7.72 0 0 0 23 3z"></path></svg>Phone</h6>
                <span class="text-secondary">   {data[0].phone && data[0].phone}</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <h6 class="mb-0"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-instagram mr-2 icon-inline text-danger"><rect x="2" y="2" width="20" height="20" rx="5" ry="5"></rect><path d="M16 11.37A4 4 0 1 1 12.63 8 4 4 0 0 1 16 11.37z"></path><line x1="17.5" y1="6.5" x2="17.51" y2="6.5"></line></svg>Instagram</h6>
                <span class="text-secondary"> {data[0].address && data[0].address}</span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
              <NavLink to="/EdiProfile"><a class="btn btn-info " target="__blank" href="https://www.bootdey.com/snippets/view/profile-edit-data-and-skills">Edit Profile</a></NavLink>   
                </div>
              </div>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
              <form action="" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="avater" id="" placeholder='Please Upload Your File' />
                <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" placeholder='submit' />
                </form> 
                </div>
              </div>
              </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
      <th scope="col">SN</th>
      <th scope="col">Test Name</th>
      <th scope="col">View</th>
      <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    { report.map (data=>( <tr>
    
     <th scope="row">{data.name}</th>
      <td>{data.testName}</td>
      <td> <img style={{height: '10px'}} className="img-fluid mb-3" src={`${data.img}`} alt=""/></td>
      <td>@fat</td>
     
    </tr>
   )  )}
        </thead>
        </table>
          </div>
          </div>}
          </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

it's my server site code

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs-extra')
const UpoladSchema = require("../Scheema/UploadFileUser");
const UserUpload= new mongoose.model("UploadFileUser", UpoladSchema);
const CheakLoginControler = require('../MiddleWears/CheakLoginControler');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const Uploadss=  express.static('Uploads');
router.post("/UserReport",fileUpload(),Uploadss,async(req,res)=>{
  const file= req.files.File;
const name= req.body.name;
const testName= req.body.testName;
const date= req.body.date;
  console.log(req.files.File)
  const filepath= `${__dirname}/../UploadsTestReport/${file.name}`;
    file.mv(filepath ,err=>{
      try {
        return res.status(200).json({name: file.name , path: `/${file.name}`})
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(500).json({msg:'Fild to upload image'});
      }
    })
    var newImg=fs.readFileSync(filepath);
    const encImg= newImg.toString('base64');
    var Img= Buffer.from(encImg,'base64');
    console.log(Img)
    const TestReport = new UserUpload({
      name: name,
      testName: testName,
      img: Img ,
  });
  await TestReport.save();

 })

 router.get("/ReportPost",async(req,res)=>{
  try {  
      const user = await UserUpload.find({name: req.query.username});
      // console.log(user)
      if(user&&user.length>0){
          res.send(user)
      }
      
  } catch (error) {
      res.status(200).json({
          "error": "Wrong Username and password"
      }); 
  }

   
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the value of `data.img` in `<img src={data.img}/>` is?

Comment: sure img
: 
data
: 
(17460) [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 2, 49, 0, 0, 1, 39, 8, 6, 0, 0, 0, 88, 8, 18, 239, 0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0, 4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 143, 11, 252, 97, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 195, 0, 0, 14, 195, 1, 199, 111, 168, 100, 0, 0, 67, 201, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 94, 237, 157, 93, 111, 21, 87, 190, …]
type
: 
"Buffer"

Comment: I think it should be a base64 encoded string instead of a buffer following the structure: `data:image/png;base64,<<the base64 string here>>`.

Comment: i can't understand it very well please help me

Comment: still now it's doesn;t work please help me there show a blank image don't  show original image

Answer (score 0):

First of all your image is sotred in a Buffer form so you  should convert back into base64 string from buffer

```
.....toString('base64')
```

secondly in order to show base64 image path should look like this

```
data:image/png;base64
```

you should store mime type of file then the src tag will look like this

```
yourModel.imgSource= `data:${imageType};charset=utf-8;base64,${imageBuffer.toString('base64')}`
```